# "Cast to ObjectId failed for value ...." error. Wanting to intercept to create my own error message but getting confused

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I just graduated from a Full Stack Bootcamp and this is my first post. I am still trying to learn and apply all of this stuff. Working on a portfolio project for a server using NodeJs/MongoDB/Mongoose and am trying to figure out how to intercept the .catch error and generate my own error message. I'm making a PUT request using an object ID for a specific record and everything is working when a valid ID is passed. However, if I test using an invalid ID it goes straight to catch error and bypasses my handling of this type of scenario. Here is the code I'm trying to manipulate:

```
.put((req, res, next) => {
    Guitar.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.guitarId, {$set: req.body}, { new: true })
    .then(guitar => {
        if (guitar) {
            console.log(guitar);
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(guitar);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 403;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
            res.end(`${req.params.guitarId} does not match any guitars in database`); 
        }
    })  
    .catch(err => next(err)); 
})
```

I assumed that if I tried to pass an invalid ID then if(guitar) would return false, then return my error code. But instead it appears that if an invalid ID is sent then it never gets to that point, instead giving the "Cast to Object Id" failure outside of my if/else code. Am I approaching this incorrectly? Thanks in advance for any insight!!!

Comment: Maybe look a little more closely at the mongoose api?  When you call findbyid can you also pass in a callback that returns the mongo doc or an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Cast to ObjectId failed` is occurring before the find operation is sent to the server, so there is never a chance for the promise to resolve and move on to the `.then`.

You might try explicitly casting the value to ObjectId inside a try-catch block to handle that specific issue, or add some to the `.catch` for that error.

Comment: thanks for the help! So, if I wanted to add to the .catch, is it as simple as replacing the (err => next(err)) function with my own error generating code?

Comment: Possibly, depending on where in the process the error occurs, you might need to try-catch around the promise creation.